# Cluster Becomes Unresponsive When One Node gores OOM

Tags: distributed-computing, hazelcast

We have created a cluster with three nodes using Hazelcast 3.4.2 and I'm having 
following issue.

If one node goes OOM, other nodes become unresponsive. Sometime those nodes 
(except one that went to OOM) manage to recover however, recovery time is not predictable.

Also, we added following two Hazelcast properties as JVM parameters. However, still the issue persists in the cluster.

1. hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout
2. hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds

Please node that, cluster was started several times by giving few different values to above two  Hazelcast properties.

So I would like to know, whether this is a know-issue or not. Also, if above scenario
is a know-issue, do we have a workaround for this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your members have enough headroom? When one member goes down then the same amount of data has to be distributed among less members. It could cause memory pressure on them. I'd recommend to enabled verbose GC log and test your scenario.